# Integrate MorphoSmart sdk in android

Tags: android, sdk, fingerprint, biometrics

I want to integrate **Morphosmart sdk** (comes with Safran Morpho device, used for biometric fingerprint scanning in Aadhar) with my android app.

Morpho device is connected to android device via a USB cable, when the user give his fingerprint on the device, i want to detect it and able to save that on my android app.

I have the sdk jar, but i have googled about it more than a day, but didn't find any doc or sample until now

Please suggest some helping tutorial or sample on the same. thanks in advance!!

Comment: Anything proprietary you should ask the company for info/help.

Comment: Did you find  any solution ??

Comment: @Mayank1987 how to get Morphosmart sdk  for Android development?

Comment: I also need the SDK, Could someone point out the link for download ? Please

Comment: @maynak1987 did u solve this issue ?

Comment: where can I get the SDK?

Comment: @Mayank1987 Hey man, did you able to integrate Morphos android sdk. I'm currently facing pretty much the same situation. There are no documents describes how-to integrate it with steps and needed classes

Comment: Hi guys, Have you found any solution.I am also stuck with Morpho Android SDK.Please help me on this.